# using where clause causes invalid column name error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012.

I have written the query below which works fine apart from when I include the last line 'where NomDiff <> 0'.

It tells me NomDiff is an invalid column name. I don't understand why and don't know how to get the query to return only rows where the nomDiff is not equal to zero?

```
;with pf as
(
    select Name, Sedol, Nominal from tblTempPLF 
    where FundCode = 'CSGE'
), pc as
(
    select Name, Sedol, Nominal from tblTempPCF 
    where FundCode = 'BTCM'
)
select coalesce(pf.Name, pc.Name) Name, coalesce(pf.Sedol, pc.Sedol) Sedol, 
isnull(pf.Nominal,0) PfNom, isnull(pc.Nominal,0) PcNom, isnull(pf.Nominal,0) - isnull(pc.Nominal,0) NomDiff
from pf full outer join pc on pf.Sedol = pc.Sedol
where NomDiff <> 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `APPLY VALUES` is a good way of not having to use a subquery, or another CTE:

```
WITH    pf
AS ( SELECT
      Name ,
      Sedol ,
      Nominal
      FROM tblTempPLF
      WHERE FundCode = 'CSGE'
    ),
pc
AS ( SELECT
      Name ,
      Sedol ,
      Nominal
      FROM tblTempPCF
      WHERE FundCode = 'BTCM'
    )
  SELECT
      Name = COALESCE(pf.Name, pc.Name),
      Sedol = COALESCE(pf.Sedol, pc.Sedol),
      PfNom = ISNULL(pf.Nominal, 0),
      PcNom = ISNULL(pc.Nominal, 0),
      NomDiff = Nom.Diff
  FROM pf
  FULL OUTER JOIN pc
  ON  pf.Sedol = pc.Sedol
  CROSS APPLY(VALUES(ISNULL(pf.Nominal, 0) - ISNULL(pc.Nominal, 0))) AS Nom(Diff)
  WHERE Nom.Diff <> 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a previously defined `alias` in the `where` clause. Use the calculation instead.

```
select coalesce(pf.Name, pc.Name) Name, 
coalesce(pf.Sedol, pc.Sedol) Sedol,   
isnull(pf.Nominal,0) PfNom, isnull(pc.Nominal,0) PcNom, 
isnull(pf.Nominal,0) - isnull(pc.Nominal,0) NomDiff
from pf full outer join pc on pf.Sedol = pc.Sedol
where isnull(pf.Nominal,0) - isnull(pc.Nominal,0)<> 0
```

Comment: or another query wrapped around the one with the alias

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the alias for the column in the `WHERE` since you are creating it in the `SELECT`, change to:

```
WHERE isnull(pf.Nominal,0) - isnull(pc.Nominal,0) <> 0
```

Or you can use a subquery/cte to make the alias available to an outer query that references it.

The reason for this is that `WHERE` is actually evaluated prior to `SELECT`, the optimizer filters out rows before worrying about which fields to return.

Answer (score 1):

Just add another cte so you can use the alias

```
;with pf as
(
    select Name, Sedol, Nominal from tblTempPLF 
    where FundCode = 'CSGE'
), pc as
(
    select Name, Sedol, Nominal from tblTempPCF 
    where FundCode = 'BTCM'
), anotherOne as /* add another cte */
(
    select 
        coalesce(pf.Name, pc.Name) Name, 
        coalesce(pf.Sedol, pc.Sedol) Sedol, 
        isnull(pf.Nominal,0) PfNom, 
        isnull(pc.Nominal,0) PcNom, 
        isnull(pf.Nominal,0) - isnull(pc.Nominal,0) NomDiff
    from pf full 
    outer join pc 
        on pf.Sedol = pc.Sedol
)
select *
from anotherOne
where NomDiff <> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using `CTE`, it would be easier to just wrap that outer query as another `CTE` and then filter out the `NomDiff` (alias for the calculated column). `Alias` does not scope within the same select statement, so in order to use an `Alias` directly, you would need to wrap that either in a `subquery` or a `CTE`. Otherwise, you could also directly use the calculation in the where clause like others have suggested here.

```
;WITH pf
AS (
    SELECT NAME
        ,Sedol
        ,Nominal
    FROM tblTempPLF
    WHERE FundCode = 'CSGE'
    )
    ,pc
AS (
    SELECT NAME
        ,Sedol
        ,Nominal
    FROM tblTempPCF
    WHERE FundCode = 'BTCM'
    )
    ,calc
AS (
    SELECT coalesce(pf.NAME, pc.NAME) NAME
        ,coalesce(pf.Sedol, pc.Sedol) Sedol
        ,isnull(pf.Nominal, 0) PfNom
        ,isnull(pc.Nominal, 0) PcNom
        ,isnull(pf.Nominal, 0) - isnull(pc.Nominal, 0) NomDiff
    FROM pf
    FULL OUTER JOIN pc ON pf.Sedol = pc.Sedol
    )
SELECT *
FROM calc
WHERE NomDiff <> 0
```